# Recursive Vs iterative Traversal of a BST

Tags: recursion, iteration, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, space-complexity

If I do recursive traversal of a binary tree of N nodes, it will occupy N spaces in execution stack.
If i use iteration , i will have to use N spaces in an explicit stack.

Question is do we say that recursive traversal is also using `O(N)` space complexity like iterative one is using?
I am talking in terms of running traversal code on some platform which bounds me by memory limits.
Also i am not talking of directly implementing iteration (in which one can say either of the approaches is fine), I am implementing algorithm for `KthSmallestElement()` in a BST which uses sort of traversal through the BST.

Should i use iterative approach or recursive approach in terms of space complexity, so that my code doesn't fail in space limits?

Putting it clearly:

Here is what i implemented:

```
int Solution::kthsmallest(TreeNode* root, int k) {
    stack<TreeNode *> S;
    while(1)
    {
        while(root)
        {
            S.push(root);
            root=root->left;
        }

        root=S.top();
        S.pop();

        k--;
        if(k==0)
            return root->val;

        root=root->right;
    }
}
```

Here is what my friend implemented:

```
class Solution {
    public:
        int find(TreeNode* root, int &k) {
            if (!root) return -1;
            // We do an inorder traversal here. 
            int k1 = find(root->left, k);
            if (k == 0) return k1; // left subtree has k or more elements.
            k--; 
            if (k == 0) return root->val; // root is the kth element.
            return find(root->right, k); // answer lies in the right node.
        }

        int kthsmallest(TreeNode* root, int k) {
           return find(root, k); // Call another function to pass k by reference.
        }
};
```

**SO Which of the two is better & how?**

Comment: What is your question? Please state it clearly, and don't ask questions that might be opinion based. What do you mean by "space limits" ? Who imposes this limits? Is a space limit for the heap or stack memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you care about memory use, you should try to ensure that your tree is ***balanced***, i.e. that its depth is smaller than the number of nodes. A perfectly balanced binary tree with N nodes has depth log<sub>2</sub>N (rounded up).

It is important because the memory needed to visit all nodes in a binary tree is proportional to the depth of the tree, not to the number of nodes as you erroneously think; the recursive or iterative program needs to "remember" the path from the root to the current node, not other previously visited nodes.